# Screenshotting code from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, screenshot

Is there a way I can screenshot my code in Visual Studio Code? I would just copy paste the code onto the doc but I need to be able to resize the images to fit multiple screenshots onto one page.

I have looked around but I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: How about a regular screenshot?

Comment: @mrogers AFAIK I can't scroll while taking a screenshot on a Mac.

Comment: Screenshotting capability is not built into Visual Studio Code. Nor any version of Visual Studio. But…um…code is *text*. Why wouldn't you copy and paste? You can change the size of the text's font much more easily than you can scale an image, while preserving fidelity.

Comment: @CodyGray Its much harder to organize lots of code onto a small amount of space. The reason I'd like to use an image is because for a test in a CS class we get to use half a page of paper for notes and I planned on just putting my code for each review question onto it.

Comment: There is a way to make screenshots of any part of VSCode the same way you would screenshot parts of HTML page. VSCode is using Electron, essentially, it is running a Chromium browser modified to serve as a UI framework. So, entire interface of VSCode is an Html page. Press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open Developer Tools for your VSCode instance, in the tabs find "Elements" - you will see the DOM of your VSCode UI. Find the node you want to screenshot, right-click it and choose "Capture node screenshot".

Comment: Use the [CodeSnap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.codesnap) extension.

Comment: Try Shift + Alt + T in box

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: At the moment there are several versions of Polacode, make sure to test some because there were incompatibilities due to VS Code Updates.

Several users had that need so this is exactly what [Polacode](https://github.com/octref/polacode) is used for

It's a VS Code Extension. Can be found in the Extension Marketplace

It has an addional feature, it keeps the theme and fonts you're using in the editor.

[Demo on Mac](https://github.com/octref/polacode/raw/master/demo/usage.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension "Polacode" to print .png documents like the one attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcm2z.png).

Check in the market place and see if it suits to your requirements 
[Polacode - Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pnp.polacode)

Answer (score 0):

How about GreenShot or Snag It? You can specify a region and snap only the code you want. The image can then be re-sized or pasted anywhere using the snag it editor or other tool.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding https://www.branah.com/text-to-image which isn't exactly what I wanted but for lack of time it did the job. James Bailey's answer is better but I am on a Mac so greenshot is not available and I could not get snagit's scrollable window capture to work.